# jquery replaceWith() and delay() to fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout

I'm trying the following in order to replace existing element with the message and after a short delay fade out the message, but for some reason I cannot get it to work:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(message).hide().fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300));
```

Any idea how to amend the above to achieve exactly this?

As requested - a bit more of the code surrounding the line above:

```
$('#form_id').fadeOut(300, function() {
     $(this).replaceWith($(message).hide().fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300));
});
```

Comment: Does this work if you don't hide message?  In most modern browsers, jQuery is unable to animate things that are hidden.

Comment: No - it doesn't seem to make any difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I've spent quite a bit of time trying to solve this and have come up with a different solution - for anyone who will come across the same problem - here's what I've done - simply using javascript setTimeout() function:

```
tar.closest('#form_id').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(message).hide().fadeIn(300, function() {
         var elem = $(this);
         setTimeout(function() { 
             elem.fadeOut(300);
         }, 1000);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).hide().after($(message)).next().hide().fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300));
```

Comment: I did - but unfortunately no change (also - you have one bracket too many at the end).

Comment: I just did and it's continuously adding 'message' on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) returns the *original* jQuery object, not a fresh one containing the new content.

You can store the message object in a local variable:

```
var $message = $(message).hide();
$(this).replaceWith($message);
$message.fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300));
```

Or you can invert the logic and use [replaceAll()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) instead:

```
$(message).replaceAll(this).hide().fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
```

Comment: Is there only a problem with the animation, or does `this` not get replaced at all?

Comment: It replaces the element but the new one has applied styling of : display: block; opacity: 0; - and doesn't fadeOut after the delay

Comment: Do you mean its remains visible? With zero opacity?

Comment: Let's clarify something, just in case: do we agree that `fadeIn()` makes the element visible and `fadeOut()` hides it, not the other way around? :)